# How to perform correlation of different size

Tags: jupyter-notebook, correlation

I wrote a simple code here. I just want to perform a correlation between X and Y.

X has 35 cases while Y has 43 cases. I just want to perform a correlation of X and Y using the first 32 cases. I hope you could help me. I am using Python on Jupyter Notebook.

```
from scipy import stats
X = pd.read_csv (r'X.csv')
Y = pd.read_csv (r'Y.csv') 

corr,p=pearsonr(X, Y)
print (corr,p)
```

[Sample data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m2upydyl8zojyl3/Data.zip?dl=0) can be found here.

Additionally, I also want to perform a rolling correlation of X and Y using the first 32 cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
    X=pd.DataFrame(dict(X=X))
    Y=pd.DataFrame(dict(Y=Y))
    X=  X.iloc[0:32, 0]
    Y=  Y.iloc[0:32, 0]
    corr,p=pearsonr(X, Y)
```

I am sure many would be asking about this simple task. So I am posting how I resolved this issue. I used the iloc function to select the rows where I want to perform correlation.